# Platform-based redirect in Angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I have a module of my a that contains its own subrouting. Essentially, the only content of this page are a header and some material tabs that are linked to my routing,so I will only be displaying one of them. I would like the landing tab to be different whether I am on desktop or mobile however.

I have a service named ToolService containing the method ToolService.isDesktopOrTablet() which I usually use to do my platform detection.

Before realizing I wanted the redirectTo to point to 'list' instead of 'tree' on mobile, my routing module looked something like

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ExampleComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'tree',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    }, {
      path: 'tree',
      component: ExampleTreeComponent,
      title: 'Example Title',
    }, {
      path: 'list',
      component: ExampleListComponent,
      title: 'Example Title',
    }]
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [],
})
export class ExampleRoutingModule {
}
```

The first thing I tried was using a class-based guard. This is when I learned that in Angular 15 class-based guards were deprecated in favor of functional guards.

The second thing I tried was using a functional guard, but I was greeted with a warning message that told me that canActivate and redirectTo do not play well together as redirects are processed before guards.

Which brings me to the third solution i tried, a resolver:

```
export const exampleResolver: ResolveFn<string> = (): string => inject(ToolService).isDesktopOrTablet() ? 'tree' : 'list'

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ExampleComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      resolve: {
        redirectTo: exampleResolver
      },
    }, {
      path: 'tree',
      component: ExampleTreeComponent,
      title: 'Example Title',
    }, {
      path: 'list',
      component: ExampleListComponent,
      title: 'Example Title',
    }]
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [],
  providers: [ToolService]
})
export class ExampleRoutingModule {
}
```

This doesn't appear to provoke any error message, but it also does not appear to do anything. When I navigate to the main route, my app stays on the '' route without actually redirecting to anything, as if the resolver was never executed, which brings me to my questions:

1. is my resolver incorrect in some way?
2. is a resolver the right tool for this job?
3. if so? what am I doing wrong?
4. if not, what should I be using instead? Did I give up on guards too early?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a [`CanActivateFn`](https://angular.dev/api/router/CanActivateFn) guard.

```
function canActivate() {
   const router = inject(Router)
   if(isMobile) {
     return router.createUrlTree(['list']);
   } else {
     return true
   }
}
```

Comment: Return the string `true`?

Comment: A boolean of course ! (as partir of the signature of `CanActivate`)

Comment: When I was trying this I received a warning that `canActivate` and `redirectTo` do not work together, as redirects are processed before guards. Is that not a worry?

Comment: I'd use the guard on the `'tree'` path. Making the `''` a simple redirect to `'tree'`.

Comment: That sounds promising. Is the `createUrlTree` so that if the guard fails it redirects to list instead then?

Comment: exactly, canActivate accepts a `UrlTree` as return value and will redirect to it.

Comment: Do I need to use a factory though? The routes const is declared outside of my module, so `this.router` is not defined, is it? Or do you suggest I move this from my module to my component?

Comment: you can use `inject(Router)`

Comment: Actually one more question - do I need to include Router (and, in my case, ToolService) in my module providers when I do this?

Comment: No need for that, it's handled by the root injector.